# What's with all the index notation in General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, notation, covariance

I am self-studying General Relativity with Leonard Susskind's lectures from Stanford. The thing that is bothering me is the notation of GR, specifically, the index notation.

---

**In simple layman terms first**, can someone explain these and then move on to the more precise and physics explanation of why:

1. Why do you need all that index notation?
2. What is it good for?
3. Provide a concrete (not abstract) and a simple example of this notation in action

Answering these questions will help me understand more about GR and provide me with the basics of GR.

Comment: Your question is very vague and basic (you are asking for a GR course).  You should identify what you _do_ understand and move slowly from there.  For example, do you know "what's with" all the index notation with matrices?

Comment: @m4r35n357 Yes, I understand what the index notation means in matrices, it's for naming or numbering a component in the matrix. It to specify which component you are talking about. EDIT: Also, I would like to understand the basics first before moving on. I would be doing myself a disservice if I didn't understand the basics, so I do not regret asking.

Comment: well it is an extension of that idea.

Comment: @m4r35n357 So then, what would this notation mean? (taken from the lecture): https://gyazo.com/016ca176e9ff0771f91011029ea8f925, it's confusing to me with the y's in it with "exponents".

Comment: xm equals ym plus a term generated by multiplying the (Christoffel symbol?) c with two vectors.  If you have got this far without what I said making sense, you have missed something pretty major, and in that case I would suggest starting again from scratch with tensor analysis.

Comment: @m4r35n357 It's not that I completely didn't understand the index notation, I did understand it somewhat, but I wanted to be sure. What you said, "it is an extension of matrix indexing", now that makes sense.

Comment: @Tachyon You have to be careful about representing tensors as matrices. It is visually useful but you lose information about where the indices are when you do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Because it provides a nice, easy way of dealing with tensors and the operations that exist between them. Along with the summation convention, the index notation massively condenses the equations used in general relativity.
2. It makes manipulations in general relativity as simple as knowing a few rules on how indices can and can't interact with each other.
3. Even someone new to general relativity will be able to see that: $$T^\mu g_{\mu\nu}A_\mu=X_{\nu} \tag{1}$$ is an invalid tensor equation, because we have used the same index three times in one term (and we have the same index down twice). If we wrote this out without the index notation and without the summation convention it would be pretty hard to decipher and would not be immediately obvious that it was invalid. The index/summation conventions are ways of visually decluttering equations in GR without sacrificing important information.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. So using index notation makes for easier tensor operations and among other things as it simplifies the calculations to a more general context?

Comment: @Tachyon It doesn't really "simply calculations", since you're not actually changing the way you do numerical calculations, but it does make equations in general relativity much, much easier to read. Especially since the summation convention condenses four terms into one each time it is used. Take the geodesic equation for instance: $$\frac{\text dx^\mu}{\text d\lambda}+\Gamma^\mu_{\sigma\nu}\frac{\text dx^\sigma}{\text d\lambda}\frac{\text dx^\nu}{\text d\lambda}=0,$$ this equation has two summations on the same term which would usually mean writing out 16 terms, but we've condensed it into 1

Comment: I see what you mean. Yeah, that does make things better.

Comment: I know why we cant have more than 2 appearances of a dummy variables on one side, but why cant we have the same variables "down" twice ?

Comment: @JohnyO42 For two reasons: 1. A repeated index implies a summation. 2. Only a summation between an "up" and a "down" index produces an object that is guaranteed to be a tensor.

Answer (score 1):

The simple reason for using index notation is that most mathematicians and physicists find it to be (eventually) a natural and intuitive way of describing tensor operations. It just takes a bit of work to get to the "natural and intuitive" stage - but then $\frac {d^2x}{dt^2}$ must have looked weird when we first encountered it too.

However, index notation is not the only game in town - Roger Penrose invented and championed an alternative [graphical notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_graphical_notation). Maybe if we had been taught this from day one then you would be asking "what's with all the weird spaghetti diagrams in GR ?" instead.

Answer (score -6):

It's all about distinguishing $a-b$ from $b-a$.

Comment: -1 Because I'm really not sure what this means, or how it relates to the question. As such I do not see it as answering this question. Some elaboration will probably be useful.